# Placeholder for date field Asp.net HtmlHelper

Tags: html, asp.net, razor-pages

I am writting an ASP.NET Mvc application with razor pages. I have problem with setting initial value for date field. 
Below is my code responsible for generating date field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BudgetEntry.DateOfExpence, new { @type = "date",@id="datePicker",@class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

Html generated:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of expence must be a date." data-val-required="The Date of expence field is required." id="datePicker" name="BudgetEntry.DateOfExpence" type="date" value="">
```

I want to set this date field on specific date.

Below is what I tried without effect:

```
window.onload= function() {
    document.querySelector('#datePicker').value = "12-23-2020";
    }
```

(tried also '12/23/2020') no effect I still see window like this:
[image]

Also document.GetElementById is not working.

I tried putting placeholder in @html like this:

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BudgetEntry.DateOfExpence, new { @type = "date",@id="datePicker", @placeholder="12/03/2020" , @class = "form-control datepicker" })

without any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the id and change the date to the format "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
document.getElementById('datePicker').value = "2020-12-23";
```